# Do unmarried women become public property?

Tags: nikah, women

In a lecture video [available on YouTube](https://youtu.be/KjlmK9lq47g) (and in many more)
[Dr. Zakir Naik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakir_Naik) claimed that unmarried women become public property.

My questions -
1) Does Islam support this statement? Are there any verses in Quran or Hadith regarding this?

If yes to the above questions then, 2) What is the upper age limit for a woman to get married? Because a woman unmarried now may be married tomorrow, so when she could be public property?

Comment: Would it be possible to transcribe the relevant part of the lecture from YouTube and [edit] it into the question?  (I'd do it myself, but YouTube is blocked here.)

Comment: If every man gets only one woman, and since there are a lot of countries where women are more than men, what will these women do ? .. They can either marry a married man , which is accepted in islam , or (unfortunately) may become "public property" (meaning they may commit adultery/Zina), which is not accepted in Islam . you clearly misunderstood.

Comment: This sounds as a strange interpretation.

Comment: Why you think all women are nymphomaniac @Butarek Hd? Without getting married women can lead a honoured life.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Youtube is blocked in China?

Comment: yes she can . I am talking about his argument , that I now think you did understand well , but your question does not imply so . If women didn't find husbands , a lot of them will ,undoubtedly, think of adultery . The solution is marrying a married man . You can't convert a valid local solution to a universal one. Sharia care for the society as a whole , not only for individuals. Why will Sharia require women to not marry while they can ? .

Comment: Yes. My question is different. I have no problem in accepting the law regarding multiple marriage. But I can't accept the statement "unmarried women become Public property". It may be Zakir Naik's personal interpretation and nothing to do with Islam. That is what my question.

Comment: Marriage is mustahab (recommended) and not obligatory in Islam[1](https://islamqa.info/en/1665), refraining from fornication, adultery and prostitution is obligatory[2](https://quran.com/23/5-7) and Islam has strict rules about modesty and chastity[3](https://quran.com/24/30-31). Other than that I am not sure what you are asking ... it was Zakir Naik's personal opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Does Islam support this statement? Are there any verses in Quran or Hadith regarding this?*

The statement you re referring to (in the YouTube video) is "Either a woman gets married, or become public property."

In [Al-Mughni](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=4455&bk_no=15&flag=1) (Hanbali school of jurisprudence), [Ibn Qudamah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qudamah) says:

> وأما السنة فقول النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم: «يا معشر الشباب، من استطاع منكم الباءة فليتزوج، فإنه أغض للبصر، وأحصن للفرج، ومن لم يستطع فليصم، فإن الصوم له وجاء». متفق عليه. في آي وأخبار سوى ذلك كثيرة. وأجمع المسلمون على أن النكاح مشروع. واختلف أصحابنا في وجوبه ـ فالمشهور في المذهب أنه ليس بواجب، إلا أن يخاف أحد على نفسه الوقوع في محظور بتركه، فيلزمه إعفاف نفسه وهذا قول عامة الفقهاء
>
> <sub>*— NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> As for the Sunnah, the saying of the Prophet ﷺ: "O' young men, those among you who can support a wife should marry, for it restrains eyes (from casting evil glances) and preserves one from immorality; but he who cannot afford It should observe fast for it is a means of controlling the sexual desire," agreed upon, as well as in many other verses and narrations. Muslim agree on the permissibility of marriage but differ in its mandate. What is commonly agreed upon in the madhhab is that it [marriage] not a mandate unless one fears of committing what is forbidden then one must do what is required to keep oneself chaste, and this is the opinion of most of the jurisprudents.

This is the same view adopted by other schools of jurisprudence, and the majority of jurisprudents. Marriage is not a mandate, neither for men nor for women, but is strongly encouraged. What this means is one should definitely seek to marry, but one will not have sinned if one does not marry.

The opinion of "becmnig public property" is that of Dr. Zakir Naik, and not one that is supported by Qur'an or hadith. The reason behind Islam allowing up to four wives is undeclared to us. Any opinion on the matter is that of the person making the statement. In most cases, I find such opinions to be fallacious (e.g., the false dilemma — either/or — either a woman gets married, or she becomes public property), but this is strictly my own personal view, and is not meant in any way or form to be that of the person; rather, their opinion.

Note that the hadith quoted above is in [Sahih Muslim, Book 16, Hadith 3](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/16/3), as well as other books of hadiths' collection.

> *What is the upper age limit for a woman to get married? Because a woman unmarried now may be married tomorrow, so when she could be public property?*

There is no declared upper age limit for a woman (or a man) to get married. It is a matter of ability to support a marriage.

Comment: I heard that hadith. But as it was told to a man, so  I thought that was for male. I didn't understand why Dr. Zakir Naik required to defend multiple marriage for male(in such a bad way). Anyway good answer and your thought is similar to mine.